Why is the proof of the uniqueness of limits by the uniqueness of real numbers wrong?
I've looked at a couple answers for the proof of the uniqueness of limits and they find creative ways to reach contradictions. Though I'd like to know exactly what the problem is with using the basic transitivity of equality that applies for all real numbers, assuming the limit is a real number which I believe these answers use as an assumption eventually anyway. And if we don't know for sure that the limit symbol is a real number then how do we show that it must be by the $\epsilon$-$\delta$ definition?
Suppose for some real-valued function $f$ and for real numbers $p$ and $A$ the $\lim_{x\rightarrow p}f(x)=A$ satisfies the condition that for every real number $\epsilon>0$ there is some real number $\delta>0$ for which
$$|f(x)-A|<\epsilon \qquad \text{for }0<|x-p|<\delta.$$
And suppose there is another real number $B=\lim_{x\rightarrow p}f(x)$ that satisfies the same condition then why is it not sufficient to say that since $A=\lim_{x\rightarrow p}f(x)$ and $B=\lim_{x\rightarrow p}f(x)$ and they are all real numbers by transitivity $A=B$ and so is unique. And if there is any proof to do it is the proof that two real numbers are equal by transitivity.
Links: Prove The Uniqueness Of Limits Proof that limits are unique Show that limits, if they exist, must be unique. In other words, assume $\lim a_{n} = l_{1}$ and $\lim a_{n} = l_{2}$, then $l_{1}=l_{2}$..

It’s only after you prove uniqueness that you can use the symbol $\lim_\limits{x\to a}f(x)$.

So you can't even say $\lim_{x\rightarrow p}f(x)=A$ without proving uniqueness?

Right. Another way to say it is that a-priori, you could define the symbol on the LHS to mean the set of all $A$’s which satisfy the  $\epsilon$-$\delta$ definition which you wrote. But then keep in mind this is a set of numbers (so you can’t speak of sums/products of limits, unless you give a definition for sums/products of sets etc). The purpose of uniqueness is that this set of numbers (if non-empty) has exactly one element, and hence you can identify the set with the unique number it contains.

When you say a set of numbers, does this mean real numbers and is it the inequality symbol in the $\epsilon$-$\delta$ definition that implies that the limit must be a set of numbers?

+1 for raising your concern. It always helps to challenge proofs so that one really understands their importance.

For the uniqueness question: Suppose that someone decided to define a new version of the limit: We say that a real number $A $ is the "Lars Limit" for the function $f(x)$ as $x \to a$, denoted $\text{lars}_{x \to a} f(x)$ provided that for each $\epsilon > 0$ there exists a $\delta > 0$ so that whenever $0<|x-a|<\delta$, then $|f(x) - |A||< \epsilon$. We could then prove that both $3$ and $-3$ are the Lars limit as $x \to 2$ for $f(x) = x+1$.
Now, you might say "Well, that's dumb -- I can tell that this definition allows for two potential answers -- but not the real definition."   But, your argument about transitivity of the real numbers would seem to apply to Lars limits as well, since $3 = \text{lars}_{x \to 1} x+2$ and  $-3=\text{lars}_{x \to 1} x+2$. And in many situations, it is far from obvious whether the definition is satisfied by only one entity or by many.
And if you appeal to "Well, the Lars Limit clearly uses absolute value in a way that allows for distinct answers" someone might well ask how you know that the use of absolute value in the regular limit doesn't also, in maybe some strange non-obvious way.
(As others have commented/answered, my "equation" above is an abuse of the equal sign. We should only use it in a situation like this when there is a unique answer -- and we cannot prove it is unique just because we chose to write it with the equals sign.)

So many a time when a definition will start by saying $\lim_{x\rightarrow p}f(x)=L$ which I see often, it shouldn't say that till it has proven the uniqueness of the particular definition? And that's because the equality symbol for reals implies uniqueness and so when you state that you make the implicit unproven claim that the limit is unique before you fully state your definition. The statement about the equality should only be considered after you show the limit in the definition is unique.

Yes -- we are sometimes lazy if we know ahead of time that we are going to shortly prove uniqueness and go ahead and use equality.  (Or at least, I am.)  But formally, we should not.  Also, don't get hung up on "equality for the reals." Its just about equality. If $x$ and $y$ are things, of any type, and satisfying some definition, I cannot conclude $x=y$ unless I happen to know that satisfying that property  is a uniqueness idea. The real limit definition says that $L$ satisfies some property, given a function $f$ and point of interest $a$. Then $L$ is a limit. not the limit, until proven

Though if it’s a definition might the equality be stated to communicate the uniqueness of the limit? And in the Lars case you might say in your definition that a “Lars limit”=L an element of the Lars limit to communicate it isn’t always unique.

Formally, a definition cannot simply claim uniqueness -- but depending on the situation, I might add "The limit of a function is unique when it exists, as well show in Theorem xx below, so we will use $\lim_{x \to a} f(x) = L$ as our notation.  If I am teaching a class, I'll at least point that out aloud, if not write it in the definition. But I would (or would ask my students) to prove it.

"it shouldn't say that till it has proven the uniqueness of the particular definition". This confuses me. It's not like you have to give a different definition for each new function - you've got basically one definition, and almost immediately after that definition is given, uniqueness is proved. After that point you're done, and saying a limit equals some value is valid. In a lifetime of doing mathematics you'll only have at most two or three days when the issue of uniqueness of limits is in question.

That was poorly worded on my part -- I meant the uniqueness of the thing satisfying, for the given particular other parameters -- in this case, given $f$ and $a$, there is (at most) one limit.

By particular definition I meant a particular definition of a limit not instances of a particular definition. So the $\epsilon$-$\delta$ definition and the definition of the Lars limit would be examples. And I do mean the very first time we’re given the definition.

And apologies that was a response to my comment which was the one that was poorly worded.

I've been interpreting the use of $\lim_{x\rightarrow p}f(x)=L$ as a shorthand because it might be annoying to write the full thing again and again so in the definition when I've written it because I don't use shorthand I've been writing that for some real valued function $f$ and real number $p$, $\lim_{x \rightarrow p}f(x)$ satisfies the definition that for every real number $\epsilon>0$ there is some real number $\delta>0$ for which
$$|f(x)-\lim_{x \rightarrow p}f(x)|<\epsilon \qquad \text{for } 0<|x-p|<\delta$$

I think I am slightly confused with the meaning of the Lars limit. Does it mean that 0 is the only limit that could ever exists if 0 satisfies the conditions, and that all others aren't limits because A is the Lars limit?

No -- I'd say that both $3$ and $-3$ are the Lars limit for $x+2$ as $x \to 1$. Definitions by themselves don't imply uniqueness -- simpler example: We say that $x_0$ is a root of $f(x)$ if $f(x_0) = 0$. But of course many functions have multiple roots.  Sometimes we word a definition to say "this is the only thing that does that" -- but then the onus is un us to prove that in fact there is only one for each situation. Otherwise, you are simply claiming by fiat that there is only one.

+1 for inventing this new definition. I think this does send the message that a definition does not necessarily imply that the thing being defined is unique. +1 also for the example of roots in your comment. That makes it more obvious that uniqueness is not a guaranteed thing.

I believe I understand. If a definition states that the limit is defined by
meeting condition C. If C alone does not imply uniqueness then the limit is not unique and if it states/implies uniqueness, is mistaken. So the lars limit would likewise be logically incorrect. I think I was getting at since you're defining something if you tacked on another condition that this A must be unique to condition C then you're all good because the condition implies the limit is the limit. So if you added in your definition provided that... + "A uniquely satisfies this". it is tautologically correct.

Also according to the Lars limit as specified it is an abuse of statement to even call it a real number. Though I understand that $\epsilon$ and $\delta$ are implicitly real. I do not see how it follows from the definition that the Lars limit must be real. You'd have to tack on "and A is real" @LarsSeme

Essentially, the notation "$y = \lim_{x \to p} f(x)$" is slightly abusive until you know limits are unique; it can/should be read as "$y$ is a limit of "$f(x)$ as $x \to p$ - or, better, avoided - until you know limits are unique. Uniqueness of limits shows that this is good/well-defined notation.

When we say "y is a limit of" $f(x)$ as $x$ approaches $p$ does that mean $y$ is a real number?

Depends on which definition you are using. Limits when $p=+\infty$ and when $p=-\infty$ have a different definition from when $p$ real, but, at least in the beginning, you only need to worry about $p$ real or $p$ one of the infinities. Generalizations of the meaning definitely come up in other contexts, though @urhie

Does this mean we should also specify that the limit is a real one if we are only concerned with real numbers in its definition? And if we included the infinities as well we should also specify that in an extended definition? And from that does it then make sense that in the case of a real limit, the limit is unique by the uniqueness of real numbers? By that I just mean the facts that $3=3$ and that $a=3$ and $b=3$ implies $a=3=b$ implies $a=b$ are true.

I am realising I was isolating the RHS as the symbol we do not know and treating the LHS as something we do know and saying we know the RHS because we know the LHS. When the entirety of "LHS=RHS" is the symbol in question and equality isn't the normal notion seen as it means y is a limit. The equality is how you specify the ordinate you wish to approach. I think notation like $y \leftarrow \lim_{x\rightarrow p}f(x)$ would avoid that confusion.

This answer is more so a summary of what I've taken away from other answers, comments and further thinking. I think the notation $\lim_{x \rightarrow p}f(x)$ might sometimes be thought of as a set of things called limits which satisfy the condition of the $\epsilon$-$\delta$ definition. So every limit $l$ thereof satisfies the condition that for every real number $\epsilon>0$ there is some real number $\delta>0$ for which
$$|f(x)-l|<\epsilon \qquad \text{for } 0<|x-p|<\delta.$$
We could more familiarly denote the set of limits as $\mathbb{L}$. A limit is an element of the set of limits and satisfies the condition of the $\epsilon$-$\delta$ definition. For some real-valued function $f(x)$ and some real number $p$ if we have two real numbers $A$ and $B$ which are limits for the function $f$ as $x$ approaches $p$, we do not know that $A=B.$ Said in other words, we do not know that the cardinality of $\mathbb{L}$ is $1$ until we prove it.
$A\in\lim_{x\rightarrow p}f(x)$ is how one is supposed to interpret the notation $A=\lim_{x\rightarrow p}f(x)$. So I think the meaning of the symbol "$=$" is actually the meaning of the symbol "$\in$" in set theory and that the equality symbol is being overloaded.
If however one is supposed to interpret the $\lim_{x\rightarrow p}f(x)$ as a limit which satisfies the condition of the $\epsilon$-$\delta$ definition and not the set of limits which satisfy the condition of the $\epsilon$-$\delta$ definition then I believe in that case the equality symbol is not being overloaded and that you may interpret equality instead as shorthand and that the transitivity does hold since it conveys equality with a specific limit which you should be able to say different shorthands of a limit are equal by reflexivity and symmetry.
tl;dr. If equals doesn't mean equals then use it as what it means. If equals does mean equals then use it as expected. And maybe the shorthand is how it is usually meant and that usual use is not an abuse of notation.
Aside: I think also that the uniqueness of the limit is rarely used. From what little I've observed, the epsilon delta definition has so far been used to check a proposed limit is in fact a limit. When we have a limit we are usually satisfied with that and we don't need to look for more. This provides more evidence that the limit definition uses a limit as an example and does not presuppose it is the limit. It is also treated this way in Tom Apostol's Calculus I he never proves the uniqueness of the definition just goes on to show some things are limits by satisfying the definition's condition and shows continuity not shortly after.
I only stumbled on this because my calculus class had a question to compute the limit and I wanted to use uniqueness to compute it.
